# Ubuntu: how to change the right click "open with" application order?

Tags: ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick, when I try to open a plain text file using a program `x`, I do right click to access the "open with" application list. Suppose my current "open with" list is like below --

```
application z
application y
application x
```

But I want it to be like --

```
application x
application y
application z
```

i.e. I want to change the order of the list.

I know that I can fix a "default program" for a particular file, but that's not what I am looking for. My question is which file defines this "open with" preferences? and if there is any way to tweak it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Under Ubuntu 19.04 Nautilus' Application Chooser sorts the `Recommended Applications` by the last time they were used, as documented [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GAppInfo.html#g-app-info-set-as-last-used-for-type).

The applications listed under `Other Applications` are sorted by their name. If you want to make an application appear at the top of the list, you could prepend its name with a hyphen (`-`). For this you have to edit the application's corresponding `.desktop` file, located within the `/usr/share/applications` folder:

Editing of .desktop file:

[image: Editing of .desktop file]

Result:

[image: Result]